# Is there a topic for camera FOV info?

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-melodic, camera, camera-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'd like to publish info about the field of view of a camera, but I cannot find a standard topic for this information.
Before creating a custom topic I want to be sure that there is nothing just ready for it.

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357799/is-there-a-topic-for-camera-fov-info?/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2020-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The information about the camera FOV can be extracted from the camera info message of your camera, so it is kind of redundant to publish the FOV separately.
And to answer your question, there isn't a message for publishing a camera FOV, at least not in the official ROS packages.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2020-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2020-07-22**:
Do you mean using those formulas?
`fov_x = 2 * atan2( w, (2*f_x) )` and `fov_y = 2 * atan2( h, (2*f_y) )`

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2020-07-22**:
yes something like that.

**Comment by [omers](https://answers.ros.org/users/101802/omers/) on 2022-09-18**:
It will be very helpful if you could add for how to extract FOV from the camera_info message. The first comment doesn't state what each parameter is, and where it is taken from.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2022-09-19**:
W is image width and h is image height in pixels. F_x and f_y are the focal lengths, from the camera matrix K[0][0] and K[1][1]